# How to add my own functions to the library?

Tags: functions, customization

I would like to have my own functions (some sort of helper or utility functions) available all the times I run Mathematica.

How to do that?

Comment: I would recommend you write a package and execute that for example from init.m,  see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70087/131.